# How to change table row colour on click of delete button, instead of deleting a row in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am implementing a row colour changing logic in iOS table row, I am using delete button by changing caption to "change colour", and on click of that  button i want to change colour of that particular row where button was clicked.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
}
```

I tried to implement the colour change logic inside above method, but its not reflecting, and only reflecting after data reload but still the index is changing -2 rows .

How to change table colour of the row on which "Change colour(delete)" button clicked and hide the button (i.e. like cancel editing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had the right solution, all you needed to do, is to:

1. Find the right cell in the tableView using the `indexPath`.
2. Change the background colour of the selected cell.
3. Refresh the tableView at the selected `indexPath` only.

   `- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
           // 1. Find cell
           UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
           // 2. Change bg colour
           selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
           // 3. Refresh tableView
           [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       }
   }`

[Here](http://pastebin.com/AbRNvviW) is a sample viewController, how is it supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no iOS pro, so excuse my ignorance but is that a native delete button? I haven't seen that yet, so wouldn't know..

But if I was implementing this, I would define a constant at the top of your file: `#define kCellTagDelete = 99` (or some other unused tag),

Then, when your delete button is pressed, change the cell's tag `kCellTagDelete`, then call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` with the proper indexPath (you can use an array of size 1), and update your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to check if the tag == kCellTagDelete, and, if so, format appropriately.

Comment: Hi, the delete button is on a table during edit row, can you please help